# Capturar input radio con js

Tags: javascript, html, web, input

Tengo un "pequeño" formulario en mi html. Ahora la idea es con js capturar el input que yo clickee, ya sea depositar o retirar, y mandar el dato para hacer la operacion requerida. Como capturo el input clickeado? y segundo una vez que clickeo en un input quiero deshabilitar el otro, como hago??

```js
var form_operar = document.querySelector('#form_op');

form_operar.addEventListener('submit', function() {
      let error = false;

      if (!document.querySelector('input[name="depositar"]:checked') && !document.querySelector('input[name="retirar"]:checked')) {
          alert('Selecciona una tarea');
          error = true;

      }
      
      if (error) { event.preventDefault(); }


 });
```

```html
<div id="operaciones">
    <form id="form_op" onsubmit="return false">
        <label for="retirar" class="operacion">Retirar</label>
        <input type="radio" name="retirar" id="retirar">

        <label for="depositar" class="operacion">Depositar</label>
        <input type="radio" name="depositar" id="depositar">


        <input type="submit" value="Continuar" id="continuar">

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo se puede elegir una opción, entonces, lo adecuado es que ambos radios tengan el mismo nombre, en este caso, `operacion` y agregar el valor que les corresponde. Con esto también simplificas la verificación, si no se seleccionó una operación `document.querySelector('input[name="operacion"]:checked')` devolverá falso.

```js
var form_operar = document.querySelector('#form_op');
form_operar.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    let error = false;

    // Revisa si se marcó alguna de las opciones
    if (!document.querySelector('input[name="operacion"]:checked')) {
        alert('Selecciona una tarea');
        error = true;
    }
    if (error) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Finalizar
        return false;
    }
    // Valor del radio
    console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="operacion"]:checked').value);
    // Solo para evitar que se ejecute el formulario en el snippet
    // Quítalo o coméntalo en tu proyecto
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div id="operaciones">
            <form id="form_op" onsubmit="return false">
                <label for="retirar" class="operacion">Retirar</label>
                <input type="radio" name="operacion" id="retirar" value="retirar">

                <label for="depositar" class="operacion">Depositar</label>
                <input type="radio" name="operacion" id="depositar" value="depositar">


                <input type="submit" value="Continuar" id="continuar">

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: wala, que rápido :v, +1, si amigo kevin, Triby tiene razón el problema era que no estabas relacionando los name de tus input radio por el mismo nombre, por esta razón ambos podían ser seleccionables y uno no afectaba al otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciono!